# Java ternary allows you to return an int or null. How is this correct?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion from null to int possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588856/conversion-from-null-to-int-possible)

I found that the following expression compiles in java.

```
int i = false ? 3 : null;
```

When the code is executed, I get a null pointer expression which leads me to think the compiler is boxing 3 to an Integer.

What i'm wondering is - Am i correct in my assessment of the issue, and is this behavior a bug, or just a confusing feature?

This problem appears to be similar to, but not quite like this thread
[Conversion from null to int possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588856/conversion-from-null-to-int-possible)

Comment: Doesn't the accepted answer of the question you linked to explain it perfectly?

Comment: In the question I linked to, y was an Integer, not an int.  I don't see why this issue was closed because it is different from the issue linked to.

Comment: the 2nd answer gives you a link to the JLS - it has the rules for inferring the type of the ? : expression

Comment: The link is not only similar, it is the same thing to me and the response explain it very well

Comment: 3& null are autoboxed  to Integer,  and then unboxed to your int i