# returning null through conditional operator when return value is int

Tags: java, ternary-operator, autoboxing

Can anyone explain the output of this code ?

```
public class Main
{
   int temp()
   {
      return(true ? null : 0);  
   }


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main m=new Main();
    System.out.println(m.temp());
 }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) besides asking us? Have you tried to to debug it?

Comment: @Praveen if you question was also around why does it compile and fail at runtime, check my comment below

Answer (score 7):

Lets take this one by one:

first compilation: why does it compile successfully? Have a look at below code:

```
int getIntValue(){

return new Integer(0));//note that i am returning a reference here and hence even I can possibly pass a null. 

}
```

Here unboxing happens and you see this code compiling properly. Even this code runs fine.

Now coming to your code:

```
int temp()
   {
      return(true ? null : 0);  
   }
```

Couple of things here, first this is making use of ternary operator. Java specification says that if any operand is of type T and other operand is primitive, primitive is first autoboxed and type T is returned as a result of the operation. And hence here, 0 is first wrapper (autoboxed) to Integer and than return type is basically converted to Integer type(remember, we can pass null here). Now when you pass null as return type, at runtime this is casted to int premitive type.

So what we are basically doing is as below:

```
int i =(int)null;
```

**And above code basically gives you nullpointerexception.**

Comment: +1 , thats  correct , primitive int cannot hold null but Integer class can , thats why it will throw NPE

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain the output of this code ?

This will always through a `NullPointerException` . Trying to unbox `null` to `int` is a `NullPointerException`.

```
return(true ? null : 0);
```

The condition is always `true` and hence the return expression evaluates to `null`. The second and third operands are `null` and `0` respectively. Since `null` can be a value of a reference , the entire expression will be typed to `Integer` as it is the closest match to `0` and `null` . Since the return type is primitive `int` and hence the `Integer null` reference should be unboxed to `int` , while doing that it should throw `NPE` as `int` cannot hold `null` , but `Integer` can.

Refer the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> 1. If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
> 2. If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that reference type.

Answer (score 0):

it should throw a `NullPointerException`

because `return(true ? null : 0);`  in this statement it will always return null;

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException will be thrown. This is because the ternary will evaluate to a boxed type containing null, and when you unbox a boxed type containing null (which Java must do to return an int) you get that exception.

For more details see [Conversion from null to int possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588856/conversion-from-null-to-int-possible)

Answer (score -2):

It will be `NullPointerException` , because **int cannot be assigned null**

however , this code will always return null , because here you stated the **condition always** as `true` , so true part of ternary statement , that is `null` will get returned.

but this works

```
public class Test 
 {

        Integer temp()
        {
           return(true ? null : 0);  
        }


     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         Test m=new Test();
         System.out.println(m.temp());
      }

 }
```

Because `Integer can hold null value ,  primitive int cannot.`