# A better way to convert Integer (may be null) to int in Java?

Tags: java, integer, int, converters

An `Integer` can be `null`. I convert an `Integer` to an `int` by:

```
Integer integer = null;
int i;

try {
    i = integer.intValue();
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    i = -1;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use assert to make sure it's not null.

Comment: you shouldn't use assert in this case cause null is a valid execution path and could indeed happen in production

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Avoiding an exception is always better.

```
int i = integer != null ? integer.intValue() : -1;
```

Comment: Darn you and your fast fingers. I was going for the autoboxing way of `int i = integer == null ? 0 : integer;`.

Comment: avoiding C legacy notation could also be considered to be a better way by some ppl

Comment: @kocko My original answer (before your edit) without `.intValue()` works fine (Java handles the auto-unboxing). Do you think calling `intValue` explicitly is more efficient?

Comment: @Eran, by calling `.intValue()` you avoid the un-boxing and get the primitive value directly.

Comment: @kocko `.intValue()` isn't avoiding unboxing; it is _explicitly_ unboxing

Comment: @khelwood, I don't agree. If you see the source of `Integer#intValue()` you can see that the method returns the nested `private final int value;`. So, by assigning `integer.intValue()` to an `int` doesn't trigger any boxing/unboxing features of the compiler. However, having `int i = integer;` _will_ actually force the compiler to do unboxing from `Integer` to `int`. That's why I find the explicit call to `.intValue()` a bit more efficient (even there's not much performance difference) and _readable_.

Comment: How does NumberUtils or Guava not already have a method for this?  They have defaultValue(primary, fallback) for so many things, but not this.

Answer (score 25):

With Java8 the following works, too:

```
Optional.ofNullable(integer).orElse(-1)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern Java as it can be done in one assignment. The ternary expression can't.

Answer (score 4):

Java 9 introduce *Objects.requireNonNullElse*, alternative solution in Java Vanilla (without external library):

```
Integer integerValue = null;
int intValue = Objects.requireNonNullElse(integerValue, 0);
```

Comment: IMO better way than using Optional

Comment: What's the reason? I would like to learn.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have `guava` in your classpath, then I like the [answer provided by michaelgulak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28700172/378151).

```
Integer integer = null;
int i = MoreObjects.firstNonNull(integer, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Lang 3

[`ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull%28T...%29)

Java 8 Stream

[`Stream.of(T...).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Taken From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18741740/6620565